# protractor throwing 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined' on request callback

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, request, protractor, automated-tests

I'm writing UI tests with protractor and I'm uploading files directly through a RESTful service instead of using UI. I have the following method

```
var defer = protractor.promise.defer();
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 201) {
        var info = JSON.parse(body);
        defer.fulfill(info);
    } else {
        defer.reject({
            error: error,
            message: response.statusCode
        });
    }
});
return defer.promise;
```

Note: API returns 201 if uploaded successfully.

Works fine when I run the code through my IDE (in Windows), but I want to run the tests through Jenkins (over Ubuntu) and in that case I get the error:

```
E/launcher - TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined
    at Request._callback (file.js:144:34)
    at self.callback (/workspace/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Request.onRequestError (/workspace/node_modules/request/request.js:845:8)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:310:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

I'm not sure if this is related to some kind of configuration or if SO may be causing this, but I sure need guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never get both error and response, so this:

```
    defer.reject({
        error: error,
        message: response.statusCode
    });
```

will try to check the statusCode of response which is undefined whenever error is true. Maybe try this:

```
    defer.reject({
        error: error,
        message: response ? response.statusCode : null
    });
```

or something like that.

But it may be better to handle 3 cases separately like this:

```
if (error) {
    defer.reject({
        error: error
    });
} else if (response.statusCode === 201) {
    var info = JSON.parse(body);
    defer.fulfill(info);
} else {
    defer.reject({
        message: response.statusCode
    });
}
```

or maybe:

```
if (error) {
    defer.reject({
        error: error
    });
} else if (response.statusCode === 201) {
    var info = JSON.parse(body);
    defer.fulfill(info);
} else {
    defer.reject({
        error: 'Bad status code: ' + response.statusCode
    });
}
```

Or something similar.

Then you will know what is your error because currently it doesn't return the error in the response because it crashes before it has a chance to do so.

Now, the error will most likely be because of no connection to the host or something like that.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. After applying the changes I was able to see that my endpoint host wasn't entirely right, domain was missing. Marked as valid answer.